# Как можно правильно вывести выбранный селект в функции .change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть следующая Html разметка:

```
<div class="lolka">
</div>
    <select>
        <option value="" selected=""></option>
        <option label="5" value="object:564">5</option>
        <option label="6" value="object:565">6</option>
        <option label="7" value="object:566">7</option>
        <option label="7.0" value="object:567">7.0</option>
        <option label="8" value="object:568">8</option>
        <option label="9" value="object:569">9</option>
        <option label="9.0" value="object:570" selected="selected">9.0</option>
        <option label="10" value="object:571">10</option>
        <option label="11" value="object:572">11</option>
        <option label="12" value="object:573">12</option>
    </select>
```

И есть код который выводит выбранное значение селекта в определённый класс

```
var one = $('.lolka').html();
$('#select').change(function() {
  $('.lolka').html($(this).val())
});
var select = document.getElementById('select');
select.size = select.length;
```

Соответственно .val выводит значение атрибута value, ну нужно что бы оно выводило непосредственно значения внутри тегов option.
.html и .text тоже не помогают.

https://jsfiddle.net/MarkTok/drv5zps5/6/

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Бери по селектору `option:selected`:

```js
var one = $('.lolka').html();
$('select').change(function() {
  $('.lolka').html($("select option:selected").text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lolka">
</div>
    <select>
        <option value="" selected=""></option>
        <option label="5" value="object:564">5</option>
        <option label="6" value="object:565">6</option>
        <option label="7" value="object:566">7</option>
        <option label="7.0" value="object:567">7.0</option>
        <option label="8" value="object:568">8</option>
        <option label="9" value="object:569">9</option>
        <option label="9.0" value="object:570" selected="selected">9.0</option>
        <option label="10" value="object:571">10</option>
        <option label="11" value="object:572">11</option>
        <option label="12" value="object:573">12</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!!

Comment: @Маркус Можно и галочку поставить если ответ помог